# How to perform an uptime check on a Cloud Run endpoint which requires authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Cloud Run endpoint and I want to check the uptime on it.

I tried to setup in Cloud Monitoring an uptime check but the endpoint is authenticated:
[image]

I don't see how I can setup the authentication in Cloud Monitoring
[image]

Comment: Indeed, you can't. I tried many thing but only public services can be tested.